# conditionally count number of events in same group

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

Data:

```
      code<-c("ABC")

      DT<-data.table::data.table(
              ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L),
       INDX_DATE = c("2010-10-10","2010-10-11","2010-10-12",
                     "2010-10-13","2010-10-13"),
             ATC = c("ABC123", "ABC12", "ABC", "DEF", NA),
        ATC_DATE = c("2005-05-05","2011-11-11","2012-12-12",
                     "2011-11-11","2005-05-05")
    )
```

Desired output:

```
   ID  INDX_DATE    ATC   ATC_DATE NR
1:  1 2010-10-10 ABC123 2005-05-05  2
2:  1 2010-10-11  ABC12 2011-11-11  2
3:  1 2010-10-12    ABC 2012-12-12  2
4:  1 2010-10-13    DEF 2011-11-11  2
5:  1 2010-10-13   <NA> 2005-05-05  2
```

Logic:

I want to count nr of events where `ATC` starts with value defined in `code` and where `ATC_DATE > INDX_DATE`. Total number of events (unique dates) per `ID` is summarized in `NR`.

Preferably fast (data.table) solution since my dataset is huge.

/H

Comment: Is `DT[, NR := sum(startsWith(ATC, code) & ATC_DATE>INDX_DATE, na.rm=TRUE), by=ID]` fast enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a logical vector and get the `sum` for counting after grouping by 'ID'

```
library(data.table)
DT[, NR := sum(grepl(paste0("^", code), ATC) &
    ATC_DATE > INDX_DATE, na.rm = TRUE), ID]
```

-output

```
> DT
   ID  INDX_DATE    ATC   ATC_DATE NR
1:  1 2010-10-10 ABC123 2005-05-05  2
2:  1 2010-10-11  ABC12 2011-11-11  2
3:  1 2010-10-12    ABC 2012-12-12  2
4:  1 2010-10-13    DEF 2011-11-11  2
5:  1 2010-10-13   <NA> 2005-05-05  2
```

---

If more than one code

```
DT[, NR := sum(Reduce(`|`, lapply(paste0("^", code),
  \(x) grepl(x, ATC))) & ATC_DATE > INDX_DATE, na.rm = TRUE), ID]
```

Comment: I found a bug. NR should contain only unique values. If for example there are several identical ATC_DATE only uniqe dates should be counted in NR.

Comment: @hklovs in that case you may do `uniqueN(ATC_DATE[grepl(paste0("^", code), ATC) & ATC_DATE > INDX_DATE], na.rm = TRUE)`